# passing an array structure, ofstream, and interger to function

Tags: c++

before I start I would like to apologize if the solution is easy. I am a beginner when it comes to coding.

When I try to compile my c++ code I get two error codes:

1. undefined reference to 'outputFirstSheet(std::basic_ofstream&, int, Info*)'
2. error: 1d returned 1 exit status

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;




struct Info
{
    char hurricaneName[11];
    int ID;
    int life;
    int date;
    float avgWindSpeed;
    float avgRainFall;
    int totalTornadoes;
};




struct Tropicals
{
    int ID;
};

void outputFirstSheet(ofstream&, int counter, Info*);

int main()
{

    ifstream storms;
    storms.open("storms.txt");


    //This will count how many lines have information in them or are being used.
    int counter = 0;
    while (storms)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        storms.ignore(256,'\n');
    }
    //This is the end of that program

    Info names[counter];

    //Both pieces of code below will allow me to go back to the beginning of the storms.txt file
    storms.clear();
    storms.seekg(0, ios::beg);



    while (storms){
        storms.get(names[0].hurricaneName, 11);
        for(int a = 0; a < counter - 1 ; a++)
        {
            storms >> names[a].ID;
            storms >> names[a].life;
            storms >> names[a].date;
            float wind = 0.0;
            float sum = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < 5;b++)
            {
                storms >> wind;
                sum = wind + sum;
            }
            names[a].avgWindSpeed = sum / 5;
            float rain = 0, total = 0;
            for (int c=0; c < 2; c++)
            {
                storms >> rain;
                total = rain + total;
            }
            names[a].avgRainFall = total / 2;
            storms >> names[a].totalTornadoes;

            //Making sure that I skip to the next line
            storms.ignore(256, '\n');
            storms.get(names[a+1].hurricaneName, 11);
        }

    }
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Results.txt");
    outfile << fixed << setprecision(2);


    // Printing out all the info in the STORM SUMMARY SHEET
    outputFirstSheet(outfile, counter, names);

    return 0;
}

void outputFirstSheet(ofstream &outfile, int counter, Info names)
{
    cout << "The program's results can be located in 'Results.txt'" << endl;
    outfile << setw(70) << "STORM SUMMARY SHEET" << endl;
    outfile << endl;
    outfile << "Name" << setw(10) << "ID" << setw(20) << " Life  " << setw(10) << "Date" << setw(20) << " Average  " << setw(20) << " Average " << setw(20) << "Tornadoes" << setw(20) << "Storm Level" << endl;
    outfile << "    " << setw(10) << "  " << setw(20) << "in days" << setw(10) << "Date" << setw(20) << "wind speed" << setw(20) << "rain fall" << setw(20) << " spawned " << setw(20) << "   level   " << endl;

    //Start adding the data to the STORM SUMMARY SHEET
    outfile << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++)
    {
        outfile << names.hurricaneName[i];
    }




    outfile << endl << endl << "This code was created by Guillermo Molina Matus" << endl << endl;
}
```

The line that has the error is `outputFirstSheet(outfile, counter, names);`
This function is supposed to be able to use ofstream, receive the counter information, and the Struct Info name variable but for some reason, I keep getting an error.

Could someone let me know what I did wrong?

Comment: Compare your declaration of `outputFirstSheet` with your definition of it. Note the difference in the type of the third parameter.

Comment: You have a typo, you declared the function to take a `Info*`, but then defined it to take a `Info` (no asterisk).

Comment: That second error probably should say `ld` rather than `1d` (lowercase 'L', not the digit one). If so, that's just your linker (`ld`) reporting that there was at least one error during linking. If you resolve all the other errors (just one other error in your case), the "returned 1 exit status" resolves itself.

Comment: `Info names[counter];` is not allowed in Standard C++, instead you should use a vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void outputFirstSheet(ofstream &outfile, int counter, Info *names)
{
    cout << "The program's results can be located in 'Results.txt'" << endl;
    outfile << setw(70) << "STORM SUMMARY SHEET" << endl;
    outfile << endl;
    outfile << "Name" << setw(10) << "ID" << setw(20) << " Life  " << setw(10) << "Date" << setw(20) << " Average  " << setw(20) << " Average " << setw(20) << "Tornadoes" << setw(20) << "Storm Level" << endl;
    outfile << "    " << setw(10) << "  " << setw(20) << "in days" << setw(10) << "Date" << setw(20) << "wind speed" << setw(20) << "rain fall" << setw(20) << " spawned " << setw(20) << "   level   " << endl;

    //Start adding the data to the STORM SUMMARY SHEET
    outfile << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++)
    {
        outfile << names->hurricaneName[i];
    }

    outfile << endl << endl << "This code was created by Guillermo Molina Matus" << endl << endl;
}
```

Your function definition should look like this.

Answer (score 1):

In the function definition use **Info* names**

Also, the arrays are passed using pointers so you really don't have to take a pointer for Info. You can simply pass the Info array and receive it like you receive variables with value. It uses a pointer. A new copy of array is not made.